# How to generate browser authentication popup in electron.js using node.js (using web view)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, webview

I want to create a page which will generate an authentication popup as soon as the URL is load,but it is not working, I am using web view to load this page in electronjs.  The pop should ask username and password as soon as the page is open.